# MySQL LEFT JOIN is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two MySQL tables:

tbsongs:

[image]

tbalbums:

[image]

I am trying to make a query from tbsongs to add a field from tbalbums, but I am getting an error, and don't find where is the error.

Here you have my query:

```
 $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbsongs where tbsongs.index='$id' 
LEFT JOIN tbalbums AS nombreAlbum ON tbsongs.album = tbalbums.idAlbums ORDER BY titulo asc");
```

Comment: WHERE comes after all the joins and before the order by

Comment: You need to tell us what the error is. But I'm guessing you need to ORDER BY tbsongs.titulo.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` goes **after** any `JOIN` and **before** `ORDER BY` :

```
SELECT 
   n.*,m.* 
FROM tbsongs n 
LEFT JOIN tbalbums m ON n.album = m.idAlbums
WHERE n.index='$id'   
ORDER BY n.titulo ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but removing the ` characters... :)

Comment: Yes, I will, but have to wait until the system let me do it. Thank you again.

Comment: oh one thing to note. order by defaults to asc so you don't need to specify that :)

Comment: I did not. I only downvote when the user doesn't ask a correct question, or asks for people to code for them. you just had a simple mistake no need for a downvote

Comment: @JohnRuddell, thank you again, I don't understand why people down vote a question without telling why. May be he/she is an expert, I am new to MySQL and learning from people like you.

Comment: I believe I know who did. Kermit provided a comment explaining that your php method to execute the query is a bad practice, which is probably where the downvote came from. look at his comment, it will help you with the correct way's to use php when hitting the database